# How to revive ferns

Tags: watering, repotting, ferns

I have had two ferns (one is an asparagus fern and one’s a boston fern I think) and I went on vacation about two years ago, they dried and have never really recovered. Both of them have about one stem left…any suggestions on how to bring them back?

I have a grow light on for maybe 12h a day and I just got a humidifier as well. I also repotted them a week ago into a fern mix but I didn’t alter it at all (no added perlite, etc) and now I suspect the pots I put them in are too large considering the small root systems and the fact that the soil doesn’t seem to have dried at all.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome! Would you like to share a photo or two of your plants? That might help assess the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Asparagus fern isn't a true fern. It grows back seeds for propagation. Boston Ferns are propagated by spores, it's a true fern. Both Asparagus ferns and Boston Ferns are vegetatively propagated through rhizomes (i.e. underground root chunk). You've just got to water them again for couple of weeks to see the signs of revival or if the rhizome has fully dried and if that doesn't seem to work you've simply got to discard them off.